# What are the disadvantages of templates instead of interfaces? (C ++)

Tags: c++, templates

I usually implemented the following implementation using the interface, but after I knew the template, I felt that the template was very useful for realizing polymorphism. (Like Ruby duck typing)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Animal{
public:
    virtual void cry() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal{
    virtual void cry(){std::cout << "bow" << std::endl;}
};

class Cat : public Animal{
    virtual void cry(){std::cout << "nya" << std::endl;}
};

void action(Animal *animal){
    animal->cry();
};

int main(void){
    Dog dog;
    Cat cat;
    action(&dog);
    action(&cat);
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Dog{
public:
    void cry(){std::cout << "bow" << std::endl;}
};

class Cat{
public:
    void cry(){std::cout << "nya" << std::endl;}
};

template<typename T>
void action(T *animal){
    animal->cry();
};

int main(void){
    Dog dog;
    Cat cat;
    action(&dog);
    action(&cat);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it would be efficient to implement with only a template because it is statically expanded at compile time and no vtable reference occurs.

And it is very easy to write a template because there is no need to inherit multiple interface classes in the following complicated relationship.

If there is no disadvantage, I would like to always use a template to implement the interface. Is there a disadvantage?

```
#include <iostream>

class Dog{
public:
    void cry(){std::cout << "bow" << std::endl;}
    void bite(){std::cout << "dog bite" << std::endl;}
};

class Cat{
public:
    void cry(){std::cout << "nya" << std::endl;}
    void scratch(){std::cout << "nya scratch" << std::endl;}
};

class Turtle{
public:
    void bite(){std::cout << "turtle bite" << std::endl;}
    void scratch(){std::cout << "turtle scratch" << std::endl;}
};

template<typename T>
void action0(T *animal){
    animal->cry();
};

template<typename T>
void action1(T *animal){
    animal->bite();
};

template<typename T>
void action2(T *animal){
    animal->scratch();
};

int main(void){
    Dog dog;
    Cat cat;
    action0(&dog);
    action2(&cat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is like asking what are the advantages of using screwdrivers instead of hammers.

Comment: Actual type of a template needs to be resolved during compilation. Polymorphic method calls - don't. For instance, having your example in mind, one may have: `Animal* pAnimal = createDog ? (Animal*) new Dog : (Animal*) new Cat; action (pAnimal);`, and it will be dispatched correctly. How would you do the same with templates?

Comment: Try and put multiple different specializations of the same template into the same `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

There is little difference, because in the first example, you have a trivial function that a compiler can automatically inline.

That is to say, `action(&dog);` can inlines into `((Animal *) &dog)->cry()` which has more than a dog's chance of turning into `dog.cry()`.

Before making any big decisions in relation to this, the thing to do is to try this on several C++ compilers that you use, and investigate the compiled output.

Secondly, the `action` function can be moved into the class, so that instead of `action(&dog)` we just do `dog.action()`. This `action` member function can start life as `Animal::action` only: a utility function in the base class. If we find that an expression `dog.action()` is doing unwanted dispatch through a virtual and would like to eliminate it, then we have the opportunity to write a `Dog::action` function which shadows `Animal::action`. The `dog.action()` expression will then use that function.

Lastly, there is a disadvantage to just using non-virtual member functions and templates: all your dispatch is static (determined at compile time). This cannot work in situations when the type of an object is determined at run-time. For instance, suppose we have:

```
Animal *a = createAnimalFromConfigFile();
action(a);
```

the run-time config file has syntax which tells the program to make a dog, cat or whatever. We don't know at compile time what the config file may contain; the user of the compiled program may edit that.

The `createAnimalFromConfigFile` has to contain some selection statement in it somewhere to branch among different pieces of code that construct different animals, like:

```
if (type == "dog") // type field parsed from file
  return new Dog(/* parameters from file */);
else if (type == "cat")
  return new Cat(/* ... */)
else ...
```

We use the OOP style with virtual functions so that we limit this kind of proliferation of ugly code with lots of conditional switching on separately coded type cases. Once we get all our ducks (or `Duck`-s) in a row as far as constructing the object, after that, we have a base class reference to it (a pointer or reference to `Animal`) and just use the framework of virtual methods to work with it in a generic way. (Or that's what the shiny OOP brochure says.)